# How to create android button animation in proper way

Tags: android

I want to create a button animation like nexus back button in below image.
When it's clicked, it's highlighted with oval shape and then bending the transparency of background color smoothly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Approximately similar effect you can achive by selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_red" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

add this selector as `bg_selector.xml` in your `res/draweble` folder.
And then set it is as background of TextView(or other View):

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
```

P.S: All magic in  `android:exitFadeDuration`